# Why the same JS code give an error?

Tags: javascript, jsp

If I include the following script into the page `script` section in the header then it works

```
var lessons;
var _lesson;

$(document).ready(function() {

    _lesson = '${_lesson}';
    lessons= ${jsonLessonsArray}; /* this line give an error */
    ...
```

But if I place the script into resource file, then I receive an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: Because JSP is interpreting those `${}` expressions, so they're gone by the time the page contents reach the browser.

Comment: `${jsonLessonsArray}` is JSP syntax, so if you move it from that file, you may not have the variable in the context. The new file might not even be processed.

Comment: `${jsonLessonsArray}` is not valid JS syntax. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Xufox ${jsonLessonsArray} is a request variable (in JSP) which is a json aray so I need to create a JS aray from that request variable and use it later in the script